# Can I extract and automatically message users on a TG group?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I’m part of a telegram group. I can see other users on the group, and I can message them individually (and manually). Is it possible to automatically (programmatically) message all the users on the group individually? Note I am not the admin.

If it is indeed possible, is there any sample code you can share?

It would be particularly awesome if the message could be customized for admin and non-admin. This means I’d need to detect if a particular user is an admin.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get what you are looking for but I assume you have a Telegram Bot and wanna message all users in an specific group/supergroup. First I have to remind you bot can't start private message according to this [link](https://core.telegram.org/bots#4-how-are-bots-different-from-humans)

> Bots can't initiate conversations with users. A user must either add them to a group or send them a message first.

If I got it wrong feel free leave comment and I will update the answer ASAP ;-) ^_^

Comment: So in a group, one can see all the other users and can directly DM them. I know a bot cannot DM them. But is it possible using any technology to screen scrape all the members of the same group and DM them individually? This can be done from my account - if not by a bot.

Comment: Web.Telegram.org is web version of Telegram so you can use Selenium or other web scrappers for doing that. You also can make a Telegram client and using your account to message them individually . Check [Here](https://core.telegram.org/api/obtaining_api_id)